# Obtaining the ctl property from a gridview control in C#, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to obtain the ctl property that is specific to each row in a gridview. In my scenario, there is a list of titles, each title is displayed as a hyperlink using the LinkButton. When this is clicked, I would like to pass the ctl property (or what ever value is specific to that title, to the database and pull the information that is relative to the value).

I guess my first step is to obtain the ctl value. Could someone please help me get on my way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which "ctl" value are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep track of the control ID that is written to the page in the row created event.  Make a integer to increment for each row written and save it as a command argument on a link in the grid.

```
linkbutton CommandArgument='<%# Eval("some_id") %>' 

protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton) sender;           
    if (linkButton != null)
    {
        if (linkButton.CommandArgument != null)
        {
            ...some code...
        }
    }

}
```